# AngularJS: How to implement a directive that outputs its HTML?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'd like to create an `example` directive that appends its inner HTML to itself. So, this:

```
<div example>
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input id="name" type="text" ng-model="name">
</div>
```

should become this:

[image]

When inside a directive, the element already has things line `class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid"` which shouldn't be in the outputted HTML.

How would implement such a directive?

My attempt is <kbd>[here](http://jsbin.com/vawofafodaco/1/edit)</kbd>

Comment: you would need html from $compile, but not sure how to print it... given that $scope is not available during compile time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't need to transclude or use scope here, just use the `compile` function to grab the inner html and append it to the node:

```
.directive('example', function() {
  return {
    compile: function(ele) {
      var innerHtml = ele.html();
      ele.append(document.createTextNode(innerHtml));
    }
  };
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pssqeebz/)